# How to render multi row grid header and its corresponding data in ng-grid?

Tags: ng-grid

As a part of my requirement, I would like to display multi rows as header and its corresponding values in the grid.

Example: In a two column grid, its should display in the 1st column header "First Name" & "Last Name" one under the other and in the second column header "Date of Birth" & "Age" one under the other. Also the corresponding data values should display in each column for the corresponding header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. Please see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fGVVOOIwvf4GrEj3XtJ6?p=preview